# How to change language dinamically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I added a button to change language.

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(String $locale): RedirectResponse
    {
        app('session')->put('language', $locale);
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

My routes:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::get('/language/{locale}', LanguageController::class)->name('locale');
  
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

And I put this in my blade:

```
                @if (app()->getLocale() == 'es')
                    <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('locale', ['locale' => 'en'])">
                        {{ __('English') }}
                    </x-responsive-nav-link>
                @else
                    <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('locale', ['locale' => 'es'])">
                        {{ __('Spanish') }}
                    </x-responsive-nav-link>
                @endif
```

I tested it changing the locale directly in the config/app.php file and it works.
Also tried to set the locale in the AppServiceProvider but session variable "language" is not set (even though it is on the controller).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My version.Right now this is the best way for me.

Route:

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {Session::put('locale', $locale);return redirect()->back();})->name('locale');
```

HeaderController function index:

```
public function index(): Factory|View|Application
{
    $data['languages'] = Language::where('status', '=', 1)->get();

    //Get or Set current language
    $get_default_lang = 'uk';
    $default_lang = $get_default_lang ?? 'en';
    if (session()->get('locale') == null) Session::put('locale', $default_lang);
    //Get Current Language

    $get_current_lang = Session::get('locale');
    $session_language = Language::where('code', $get_current_lang)->first();
    $data['current_language_name'] = $session_language['name'];
    $data['current_language_image'] = url($session_language['image']);

    return view('common/header', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Header Blade:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="{{ $data['current_language_image'] }}" alt="{{ $data['current_language_name'] }}" style="max-width:20px;margin-right:5px;" />
        {{ $data['current_language_name'] }}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="p-2">
            @foreach($data['languages'] as $language)
                <a href="{{ route('locale', ['locale' => $language->code]) }}" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <img src="{{ url($language->image) }}" alt="{{ $language->name }}" style="max-width:20px;" />
                    <span>{{ $language->name }}</span>
                </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Language migration:

```
Schema::create('language', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('language_id');
$table->string('name', 32);
$table->string('code', 5);
$table->string('image')->nullable();
$table->tinyInteger('status');
$table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Why is the Language model needed?

Comment: I use it to conveniently retrieve data from the database if you use more one language. protected $table = 'language'; protected $primaryKey = 'language_id'; protected $fillable = ['language_id','name','code','image','status'];